# Context hybris Global Context Factory couldn't be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'marshaller'

Tags: spring, exception, sap-commerce-cloud

I am following wiki hybris [core trails](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/hybris+5+Developer+Training+Trails+5.4+-+Part+I+-+Core) on hybris 5.5.1 with jdk 1.8. Everything is working fine for me in that cuppy project but I cannot execute any of the test [case](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Trail+~+Events) given in that trail. Whwnever i try to run as junit test of any of test class I get exception as :-

org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, **Error creating bean with name 'marshaller': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException**: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "de.hybris.platform.cuppy.ws.openligadb.types" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:

Here is the stack trace I Am getting regarding exception on my console :-

[0;32mINFO  [main] (junit) [HybrisContextFactory] Loading <> spring config from extension (cuppy) located in (global-cuppy-spring.xml,cuppy-ws-spring.xml) took: (63.76 ms)
[m[0;33mWARN  [main] (junit) [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
[morg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'marshaller': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "de.hybris.platform.cuppy.ws.openligadb.types" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:**
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "de.hybris.platform.cuppy.ws.openligadb.types" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.refreshContext(HybrisContextFactory.java:98)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:176)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:113)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1059)
    at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(RegionCacheAdapter.java:75)
    at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getOrAddUnit(RegionCacheAdapter.java:205)
    at de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit.get(AbstractCacheUnit.java:180)
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.ComposedType_HJMPWrapper$FindAll0FinderResult.getFinderResult(ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.java:1543)
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.ejbFindAll(ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.java:1598)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities.callMethod(Utilities.java:1069)
    at de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities.callMethod(Utilities.java:1059)
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.framework.HomeInvocationHandler.invoke(HomeInvocationHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.TypeManagerEJB.getAllItemTypes(TypeManagerEJB.java:177)
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.loadAllTypes(DBPersistenceManager.java:631)
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.loadPersistenceInfosInternalInTX(DBPersistenceManager.java:614)
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.loadPersistenceInfosSafe(DBPersistenceManager.java:569)
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.DBPersistenceManager.loadPersistenceInfos(DBPersistenceManager.java:539)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:702)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:656)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:639)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:700)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:544)
    at de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities.setJUnitTenant(Utilities.java:1472)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.runlistener.PlatformRunListener.testRunStarted(PlatformRunListener.java:44)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.ChainingRunNotifierWrapper$1.notifyListener(ChainingRunNotifierWrapper.java:97)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.ChainingRunNotifierWrapper$SafeNotifier.run(ChainingRunNotifierWrapper.java:239)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.ChainingRunNotifierWrapper.fireTestRunStarted(ChainingRunNotifierWrapper.java:99)
    at de.hybris.platform.testframework.HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.run(HybrisJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "de.hybris.platform.cuppy.ws.openligadb.types" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "de.hybris.platform.cuppy.ws.openligadb.types" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:888)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:463)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ...

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the *Junit* tenant :

```
ant yunitinit
```

Comment: if that ant target no longer exists (it got removed in some recent version) you can also do 
"ant initialize -Dtenant=junit" to initialize the junit tenant

Comment: it's still available under V6, when has it been removed ?

Comment: Just checked it's also available under V6.1

Comment: @BenoitVanalderweireldt I initialized junit tenant but then too its showing the same exception . Although my test cases are working fine on hybris 5.4 but in hybris 5.5.1 , test cases are working fine on hybris Testweb Frontend (localhost:9001/test) only. I have tried to run the test through eclipse but its showing error as shown in question.

Comment: Could you share your spring xml config ? *global-cuppy-spring.xml,cuppy-ws-spring.xml*

Answer (score 0):

Try to add cuppy classes folder in 'Run Configurations'. ObjectFactory.class is generated there.